# CMake - eliminate obsolete 3rd-party library download

Tags: download, cmake, googletest

I add to my project gtest as external project, and for clean install
I download and recompile it, as shown in the code below. I works fine, but in every single development step, when I add a test case, checks the repository, delaying the execution, and when I am off-net, even the make step fails.
How can I explain CMake, that this download, check, etc, is ONLY needed if I make a build form scratch? (I.e. when gtest is available, no action needed?)

```
# Add gtest
ExternalProject_Add(
    googletest
    SVN_REPOSITORY http://googletest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
    SVN_REVISION -r 660
    TIMEOUT 10
    PATCH_COMMAND svn patch ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/gtest.patch ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ThirdParty/src/googletest
    # Force separate output paths for debug and release builds to allow easy
    # identification of correct lib in subsequent TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES commands
    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
               -DCMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG:PATH=DebugLibs
               -DCMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE:PATH=ReleaseLibs
               -Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON
    # Disable install step
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    # Wrap download, configure and build steps in a script to log output
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
    LOG_CONFIGURE ON
    LOG_BUILD ON)
```

Comment: Just add *parameter* to your CMake script, which will denote that local version of `gtest` should be used instead of downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExternalProject_Add` function has the `UPDATE_COMMAND` option. Setting this option to empty string `""`, just like you do for `INSTALL_COMMAND`, disables the update step.

According to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/module/ExternalProject.html) for CMake 3.4, there is also a `UPDATE_DISCONNECTED` option to achieve the same result. I didn't try it myself, so I'm not sure it works as I understand.

Comment: You could also try having CMake download gtest during the cmake stage rather than the build stage, then use add_subdirectory() to make gtest part of your actual build. This has advantages beyond just moving the download to the cmake stage. See [here](http://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/) for details.